# How to build libzmq library for android with statically linked lib std

Tags: android, c++, clang, zeromq

I am trying to build libzmq library for android using scripts in libzmq/builds/android folder. Everything is fine but my result library is dynamically linked to libc++_shared.so.

Based on documentation from NDK I have to set an option -static-libstdc++ to linker. I was trying to add to

```
ANDROID_BUILD_OPTS+=("LDFLAGS= -static-libstdc++ ${ANDROID_BUILD_LDFLAGS} ${ANDROID_BUILD_EXTRA_LDFLAGS}")
    ANDROID_BUILD_OPTS+=("LIBS= -static-libstdc++ ${ANDROID_BUILD_LIBS} ${ANDROID_BUILD_EXTRA_LIBS}")
```

but seems those flags are ignored

Did anyone manage to build libzmq with statically linked lib std ?